# Qt Creator Open Frameworks "must recompile with -fPIC"

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator, openframeworks, fpic

I am trying to build/run an example openFrameworks QtCreator project. The project builds up to a point then throws these errors:

[image]

It says I should recompile some libraries with -fPIC? How would I go about doing that if that is indeed the fix for my issue?

I am very new to linux and even newer to openFrameworks and QtCreator so I assume this is something I have done wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the wrong version of OF. getting the gcc6 version fixed it.